# Set DB saving on some time and date with mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to save an sql tables on some date, time and than set all values by default to start new table value from new year.
i have a table, it is working fine, but when will comes new year i need to back up all data in tables and from first day of next year start all tables values from default. I want to set this procedure automate with mysq

Comment: Please be more clear in the structure of your SQL tables and the name of the field which you need to set to something else. If you do that, someone can probably help you use a `select ... into` clause to save the data to a backup, and then an `update` statement to update your data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: @O.Kuz If you have more information to clarify your question, please [edit] the question to include it there - it makes your question easier to understand.

Comment: I guess!!! you need to do some logical partition of your table.